# Некоторые аудио файлы .ogg из массива бесконечно проигрываются

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Привет. Пишу аудио проигрыватель под Android. Проблема в следующем: есть коллекция (`LinkedList`) путей аудио файлов. Цель: MediaPlayer должен после воспроизведения одного переходить к воспроизведению следующего.

`OnCompletionListener()` реализован так, что в методе `onCompletion()` по окончании воспроизведения проверяется наличие следующего элемента-файла в коллекции и при наличии такого вызывается `start()` MediaPlayer`a.

Не могу разобраться почему, но 1 файл, проигрывается - включается 2 файл,
он тоже проигрывается - включается 3 файл,
он тоже проигрывается - включается 4 файл, и вот он уже проигрывается бесконечно, дальше опять несколько файлов проигрываются и следующий опять бесконечно.

Параметр `Looping()=false`, все файлы имеют расширение .ogg, эти файлы 3 и 4 секунды, другие более длительные, другие менее длительные.
Т.е. `onCompletion()` вообще не вызывается в этих двух случаях.

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Воспроизведение закончено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(lllZZZ.listIterator(indd+1).hasNext()){  
        if(!new File(lllZZZ.get(indd+1)).isDirectory()){
            indd=indd+1;
            startmp(indd);
        }
    }
    else{
        indd=indffZZZ;
        startmp(indffZZZ);

    }
}
```

Таким образом не происходит переход к следующему файлу.
Кто что думает почему?

Comment: Под дебагом данный код на четвертый раз как выполняется? корректно?

Comment: Да вызовы происходят те же самые, что и на других файлах.